# How to Call C# Azure Function App from XSLT 3.0 (Logic Apps)?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, saxon, xslt-3.0

**How would I, in XSLT 3.0, that's running in Azure Logic Apps, call out to a C# Azure Function App so that I can get the value I need from it?**

Right now I have an XSLT 1.0 map that runs in Biztalk today. One piece of this map contains code that calls out to a C# function in an external assembly via extension objects. And that C# calls out to a SQL table to get a value that it returns back to the XSLT file to complete its transformation. A little ugly.

The plan is to rebuild this XSLT 1.0 map, but in XSLT 3.0, so I can clean up some old code and simplify some things. I'm also moving to Azure Logic Apps instead of Biztalk. And finally, I've already built a C# Function App that replaces the need for SQL. It just returns a single string - it'll be a global function app that many XSLT 3.0 files will eventually call to get data.

I would like to use inline C# to call the function app from the XSLT itself, but inline C# requires msxsl, which the Saxon processor does not support. Would I *have* to use an external assembly stored in Azure Integration Account that will essentially act as a C# helper that will call the Function App? Or is there some sort of functionality in XSLT 3.0/Saxon that handles this that I'm not aware of?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The .NET framework version of Saxon HE has its extension mechanisms to call into C# documented at https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-simple-N.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-fns-N.html. How/whether that is usable in the context of an Azure logic app is something I don't know. As for other mechanisms, XSLT 3.0 can process JSON e.g. do `parse-json('https://someazure-function/endpoint?arg1=value1&arg2=value')` (do a GET request), perhaps that suffices for your needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SaxonCS doesn't have any capability to execute "inline" C# embedded within stylesheet code. It does, however, have the ability to call out to C# functions that are registered with the processor as part of the invocation API. I'm not quite sure how this relates to your Biztalk/Azure infrastructure, but somewhere there will be some C# code that invokes a Saxon transformation, and at that point you can register a callback function that will be visible within the stylesheet.

See Processor.RegisterExtensionFunction (2 overloads) at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api/Processor